# Recover code after crash

Tags: delphi, crash, delphi-xe5

I have been working all morning on a procedure and forgot to save (yeah i know im dumb). Now rad studio crashed and i'm looking for a way to recover my code. Is there one?

Comment: The only way I can think of is travel in time.

Comment: ah nice, could you write me a snippet?

Comment: If you have a dump of BDS process, then anwer would be *yes with some efforts*.

Comment: i do have a dump. can you point me in the right direction so i can read/open it somehow?

Comment: Have you looked in the `__history` folder?

Comment: yeah last one was made yesterday

Comment: What about **Tools | Options | Editor Options** and then the **Create backup files** option. Is that checked or not?

Comment: it is checked. where do i find those backup files? the files in the 'hystory' folder are old

Comment: They are probably files like xxx.~pas alongside the originals. Not sure when they get saved.

Comment: allready searched all the *.pas files on my pc. Last one was made just before i got started. Thank you all for the info. I'm just gonna rewrite my code.

Comment: @TLama When you get that timetravel thing sorted out. Just give me a poke

Comment: Well, even that's not so easy. Think about retrocausality. If you would travel back in time and saved your work, you wouldn't ask this question and I couldn't help you to travel back in time, which then leads to not saving your work again. But I could make a backup for you in the past and send you it over IPoAC :)

Comment: @TLama: So essentially this will create an infinite loop. The universe will stackoverflow...

Comment: @TLama Acually i'm a strong believer in a mulieverse. Saving my work will result in a happy me in a diffirent dimention. (It will also result in the distruction of Vulcan, but whatever)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from time travel which is already mentioned in the comments I think there is no other way to recover your code. But you can avoid this in the future by installing [DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ddevextensions/). This extension creates backups of your files after every successful compile. Or you can check Autosave in the Editor Options, which saves your files after every successful compile.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have checked the autosave. Cant give you the V (there is no answer atm), but will give you a +1

Answer (score 0):

In the source folder, Delphi will keep track of the history of your files.
Maybe it is in there though I believe you will need to have auto save enabled for this.
After all, it is the saved history...